# Find n nearest points with Solr in multi-dimensional space

Tags: solr, nearest-neighbor, n-dimensional

Solr experts, I'd really appreciate some advice on my problem.

I want to build a multi-dimensional space using Solr, let's say with 5 dimensions. In this space, there should be points, e.g.

```
P1 (0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3)
P2 (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1)
P3 (0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
```

Now I'd like to find the point that is nearest to a given point, e.g.

```
Px (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

I've tried to find reliable information about multi-dimensional spatial search. But I could not find anything that was of help.

In the Solr Wiki is an article about [Spatial Search](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search). But there they are only using 2 dimensions.

So my question is: Does Solr provide the functionality for a multi-dimensional spatial search?

Comment: I don't think Solr handles anything above 2 dimensions. But it can handle expressions, you could try to adapt one of the many ways to find nearest neighbour in N-Dimensional space to something solr will understand, but i don't think it will work very fast.
The only other way i can see it working is dividing the 5 dimensions into https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=permutations+of+5+elements+taken+by+2 and have all 20 fields as distances and find the one with the smallest sum of all of them

Comment: I was afraid that Solr does not provide the functionality. I think the suggestion to divide the 5 dimensions into permutations won't fulfill our requirements regarding performance. Nevertheless, thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: This is supported in lucene.  I'm still trying to figure out how to do it in solr.  http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/lucene/document/DoublePoint.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either [Principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) or [T-distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding) to reduce your 5-dimensional space to a 2-dimensional representation, and then you can use Solr to find the nearest neighbors for any point on your dataset.

According to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238538/are-there-cases-where-pca-is-more-suitable-than-t-sne), it seems that t-SNE is the most suitable option for your problem.

There is a [Python t-SNE tutorial here](https://github.com/oreillymedia/t-SNE-tutorial) but I think this would be enough to solve your problem:

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
X = np.array([ [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1], [0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5] ])
reduced_points = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0, angle=.99, init='pca').fit_transform(X)
reduced_points = [ [int(x[0]*100), int(x[1]*100)] for x in reduced_points ]
```

And then you'll get your points in bidimensional space.

```
>>> reduced_points
[[-21020, 2023], [-12745, -16097], [-2899, 10298], [5375, -7822]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported in Solr, but it is supported in Lucene.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/lucene-points-6.0